# Is $\lim_{x\to -3}\frac{x^2+9}{\sqrt{x^2+16}-5} = \infty$?

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

It was asked in our test, and below is what I did:

$$\lim_{x\to -3}\frac{x^2+9}{\sqrt{x^2+16}-5} $$

$$=\lim_{x\to -3}\frac{x^2+9}{\sqrt{x^2+16}-5}\times\frac{\sqrt{x^2+16}+5}{\sqrt{x^2+16}+5} $$

$$=\lim_{x\to -3}\frac{x^2+9}{x^2-9}\times \left(\sqrt{x^2+16}+5\right) $$

Now no terms cancel. We get 0 in numerator and denominator too.

**Ans:** My teacher told me that the limit is $+\infty$, but didn't tell how.

Comment: The denominator tends to $0$, numerator remains finite, why do you doubt the fraction increases without bound?

Comment: @Macavity the numerator has one factor which is becoming $0$.

Comment: Which factor does $x^2+9$ have which tends to zero as $x \to -3$?

Comment: @Macavity $\sqrt{x^2+16}+5$

Comment: That's in the denominator, isn't it? How is it a factor of the numerator?

Comment: "We get 0 in numerator": hem, how ?

Comment: If your teacher told you the answer is $+\infty$, then the original question was either the left-hand limit or the answer is wrong (or at least: incomplete).

Comment: _[reaction to a deleted comment... might still be useful]_ The numerator is always positive, as is the expression under the square root. The denominator however, becomes negative when $\sqrt{x^2+16} < 5$, which happens when $|x|<3$, so also for $x \to -3^+$.

Comment: try lhospital....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The numerator is positive for both LHL and RHL, but the denominator is $\rm +ve$ for one and $\rm -ve$ for other:

$$\begin{align}\text{Since }\\
&\text{as }x\to-3^-,\ \ \sqrt{x^2+16}-5 >0 \\
&\lim_{x\to-3^-}f(x)=\infty
\end{align}$$

$$\begin{align}\text{also,}\\
&\text{as }x\to-3^+,\ \ \sqrt{x^2+16}-5 <0 \\
&\lim_{x\to-3^+}f(x)=-\infty\\ 
\end{align}$$
$$\rm RHL\neq LHL \implies \text{lim D.N.E}$$

Comment: Shouldn't the LHL be $\infty$ and RHL be $ -\infty$ ?

Comment: While I see what you are trying to say, your notation is wrong. The statement $$\lim_{x\to -3^-}\sqrt{x^2+16}-5<0$$ is false, because the limit is *equal* to 0. It is true, however, that the expression is smaller than $0$ for $x<-3$

Comment: @vnd sorry yes!

Comment: @5xum yes true, but i cant figure out how to express that. You are absolutely correct that the limit itself is equal to zero, but i want to say that denominator remains negative.

Comment: @Tim If $x\rightarrow -3^-$, then note that $x^2 + 16 \gt 25$

Comment: @Tim Why not just say "$...<0$"? I mean, that's sort of the default way of saying it, isn't it?

Answer (score 3):

Given limit does not tend to $\infty$. This is the graph of $f(x)=\frac{x^2+9}{\sqrt{x^2+16}-5}$ in WolframAlpha.

[image]

As you see,
$$
\lim_{x\to -3+0}f(x)=-\infty
$$
and
$$
\lim_{x\to -3-0}f(x)=\infty.
$$

Answer (score 2):

$$\lim_{x\to -3}\frac{x^2+9}{\sqrt{x^2+16}-5} $$

As $x\rightarrow-3^+$, we have the numerator, $x^2+9\rightarrow18$, and the denominator, $\sqrt{x^2+16}-5\rightarrow0$ from the left side on the number line.

As $x\rightarrow-3^-$, we have the numerator, $x^2+9\rightarrow18$, and the denominator, $\sqrt{x^2+16}-5\rightarrow0$ from the right side on the number line.

Thus, the fraction, $\lim_{x\to-3^+}\frac{x^2+9}{\sqrt{x^2+16}-5}\rightarrow-\infty$ and $\lim_{x\to-3^-}\frac{x^2+9}{\sqrt{x^2+16}-5}\rightarrow+\infty$.

Comment: Careful: the limits from the left-hand and right-hand side are not the same.

Comment: You have $[\frac{const}{0}]$ so you have to compute LHL and RHL.